# I need help in creating an HTML5 Video Player with an Playlist that automatically plays all videos in the Playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

First of all, I'm not a programmer, I have some basic knowledge in HTML and CSS but when it comes to javascript I'm pretty much lost.
I found this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jzs6B/655/ with an HTML5 Player with a Playlist, is there any possibility to upgrade this player, so that it begins to automatically play the first video in the playlist once the player is loaded, then the second when the first one ended and so on until all Videos in the Playlist have been played from the top to the bottom?

Here is the relevant javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mouseover demo</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #videoarea {
    float:left;
    width:640px;
    height:480px;
    margin:10px;    
    border:1px solid silver;
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var i = 0;
        var totalVideos = 2; //have added 3 videos to source 0 - 2
        var myArray1 = new Array(
"http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4",
"http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4",
"http://html5example.net/static/video/html5_Video_VP8.webm");
        var now = 0;
        $(function () {
            $("#videoarea").attr({
                "src": myArray1[0]
            })

        });

        function next(e) {
            i += 1;

            $("#videoarea").attr({
                "src": myArray1[i]
            });
            if (i == totalVideos ) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="AnchorHolder" style="width:50%; height:50%;">
        <video id="videoarea" onended="next(this)" controls="controls" poster="" src="" autoplay></video>
    </div>
    <button onclick='submitForm()'>
        Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Explanation:
1)Store the videos source as an array.
2)Set a counter i = 0 and number of files
3)On onend of a video change src to next object in the array , and set the counter so that it gives 0 after the last video is played.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more help. And also accept if the answer solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your example works perfect in Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE.
I copied your code to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jzs6B/656/ ,it's also not working there.
Do you have any idea why it's only working in Firefox? This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks again.